# (Unsuccessfully) testing the effects of indexes in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I am learning about all things SQL, and upon reading about indexes I naturally wanted to create a simple adhoc test to see how indexes REALLY affect performance (rather than just taking the reading at face value).  However, I am having some big problems with the tests I was trying to set up.  In short, no matter how big I make my tables, with or without indexes, the queries finish very quickly, on average 0.5 seconds every time.  I was hoping that I could create some tables so large that certain queries would take a long time to execute, and then by creating indexes I could reduce those execution times, and compare the reductions against different types of indexes.  However, I am having no luck at all!  Here is how I set up my sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(EmpID  NUMBER(6),
Lname VARCHAR2(20),
Fname VARCHAR2(20),
Gender CHAR(1),
HomeState CHAR(2),
BirthDate DATE,
HiredDate DATE,
Occupation VARCHAR2(20),
Salary NUMBER(6),
NumDep NUMBER(1));
```

The EMPLOYEE table has 10 attributes, and I created a separate Java program to make SQL commands to populate the table with random info.  For example, here is the output from the Java program with an input size of 3:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 'HENRY', 'VIRGINIA', 'F', 'MA', '14-NOV-1966', '27-APR-1987', 'MANAGER', '80514', '5');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 'PARSONS', 'KEVIN', 'M', 'KS', '11-DEC-1961', '14-JAN-2004', 'NURSE', '74416', '3');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (3, 'GARRETT', 'JIMMY', 'M', 'NE', '24-MAR-1963', '20-MAY-1992', 'SERVICE', '87116', '2');
```

The last name is chosen from 500 common last names randomly.
The first name is chosen from 100 gender-specific first names randomly.
The state is chosen randomly (from a list of 50, obviously).
The dates are chosen randomly within certain reasonable limits.
The occupation is chosen randomly from a list of 20 common jobs.
The salary is chosen randomly between 50000 and 99999 (which leads to some unrealistic salary/job matches, but that is not really the point here).
The number of dependents is chosen randomly between 0 and 5.

I figured that one good thing about the above setup is the range of domain sizes.  I.e. 500 last names possible, 100 first names possible, 50 states, 20 jobs, etc.  I know from reading that indexes work better when the amount of possible values is smaller compared to the overall number of records, and I was hoping to be able to prove this with my testing.  However, as I said before, my testing is failing horrible.

I started off populating the EMPLOYEE table with only 500 records, and found that every query I did (example below) took only 0.5 seconds in SQL Developer (the software I am using to connect to Oracle 11g).

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE salary BETWEEN 60000 and 62000;
```

So then I tried with 1,000 records, then 10,000 records, then 100,000 records, then 500,000 records (which I had to insert in batches of 100,000 since my clipboard and/or SQL Developer can't seem to handle such large script)... and the results are still the same.  It solves every query in 0.5 seconds!  Which blows my mind since it takes over 60 seconds to insert 100,000 records.  Also SQL Developer can't seem to return more than 5,000 results in a single query script execution, and if I come close to this max sometimes it takes 1.0 seconds instead of 0.5 seconds, but I suspect this is mainly because of the time needed to print all 5,000 results in the script output window.

I have tried my queries on various attributes, and I've tried with and without indexes on those attributes, and the indexes seem to make no difference.  I am very disappointed here.  I was expecting my testing to yield much more tangible results.  I was also hoping to use this topic, along with the results of this testing for a class paper that I need to write soon, but with my testing yielding no results that is going to be kind of hard.  Any suggestions?

P.S. Thanks for reading this far if you did!  Really sorry for the length...

Comment: I'm still digesting all the info out there on EXPLAIN PLAN and AUTOTRACE, but I had a new question.  Rather than the giant dummy table I tried to create above, is there a standard benchmark table (or set of tables) that exists out there that I could be using for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing `SELECT *`, Oracle is basically going to have to retrieve all the blocks for your table no matter what, so it's very possible that it's not using your index. To determine if it's using your index, you need to look at the explain plan or the execution plan. That will tell you what route Oracle chose to get your data, a full table scan, an index scan, etc.

Here's some documentation on using [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm) in 10g.

As for the times in SQL Dev, once Oracle has read all the data blocks for the table, it holds them in cache for a while. That's part of the IO that often takes the longest. The 5000 limit in SQL Dev can be set somewhere in the options, but I forget where.

You might be better off doing this in SQL*Plus, and setting AUTOTRACE to on. You can get a record of the actual IO calls that way. Look for "db block gets" and "consistent gets", I think.

Really, without an execution plan or an explain plan to tell us what Oracle is really doing to get your data, it's hard to tell if it's even using your indexes.

Comment: Finally got a chance to read through that whole link you posted for me.  Half of it went over my head at my current Oracle experience level, but some of it helped me.  I will test it out later tonight with my current "test table."  A question more related to my original post.. how can I design a more complex table that really will require 10-30 second queries?  Obviously my 500,000 row table failed miserably... how complex do I need to get?  Is it impossible with just one table?  I know the times are less important than the "cost," but I still want to make a query that just GRINDS my system..

Comment: I found out that SQL Developer has AUTOTRACE option also, but I'm already getting confused again.  The same query will report only 70 "consistent gets" in SQL Dev, but 4400 "consistent gets" in SQL Plus.

Answer (score 2):

Try autotrace in sqldev worksheet (the button is second-next to the run). Autotrace in sqldev is essentially explain plan amended with execution statistics on rowsource level. The columns to pay attention to is "elapsed time" and "buffer gets" (logical IO). You may also want to watch number of rows processed at each stage.

The blocks can be cached by multiple layers: by RDBMS, by OS, by disk cache (is your drive solid state by any chance?); so you effectively have no control over elapsed time in your test setup. Yet, you will see profound difference in buffer gets, and autotrace will expose in detail what happens on rowsource level. In a word: logical IO is much less volatile performance metric than elapsed time.

Edit: you may also want to pay more attention to your test detail. If you are measuring client wall clock (that is what sqldev displays on the grid toolbar), then it is the worst possible time metrics. Consider measuring timing on server side and, preferably, pure execution time (query run time minus soft parse). this is what is shown in different performance dictionary views/tkprof. Second, sqldev fetches only first 100 (or so) rows, while you seems to want benchmarking full table scan. Consider replacing `select *` with `select count(col)` where `col` is not covered by any index -- additional aggregate operation usually inflicts negligible overhead.

Comment: Yes I actually am on a SSD and I considered that.  Before I posted here, I took the time to install Oracle on a laptop with only HDD, which was considerable, and even there the results were similar.  But yes, it sounds like you are right and I should be utilizing autotrace and explain plan, which I will look into more soon.  Is there not a "physical IO" metric to accompany the "logical IO"?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2122.htm DISK_READS? Again, this is what RDBMS thinks is physicl IO -- it is ignorant of the other layers.

Comment: I've been playing around with Autotrace both in SQL Dev as you recommended and in SQL Plus as others recommended.  I am not sure why the "consistent gets" are radically different for the same query in each environment.

Comment: There is a hidden panel that shows statistics on statement level. It is essentially the diff of V$MYSTATS before and after execution. Hover the mouse over the split pane divisor to expand it. I suggest the data in this panel would be the same as in SQL*PLUS. Next, statistics on statement level includes overhead related with execution of auxiliary stuff, fetching stats, and parse I believe would fall into it. The execution on rowsource level is precisely what it takes to execute a particular RA operator.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your data is being cached in memory and your queries are simply retrieving the data without actually doing disk I/O. You'll want to flush the buffer pool between each query to see if that's the issue:

```
alter system flush buffer_cache;
```

I am assuming this is a database on your own system and you won't be affecting anyone else by doing this.

Comment: Yeah, I actually found that flush command in the past hour on my own after reading the response below which mentioned a cache.  Unfortunately (and surprisingly), it seems to make no difference.  Even after a cache flush it still goes super fast.

Comment: @Johnson: Even if flushed from the Oracle cache, data is probably cached by your filesystem or disk hardware.  Investigate logical changes (indexes) using logical measurements (blocks read) so that physical considerations do not dominate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using `tkprof` this will show you the detail of the running query, and the execution plan of your query as it run on your server (rather than the execution plan of your query run from your client, they can differ)

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/sqltrace.htm

also I'm not sure I would go down the buffer flushing route, (as this is not a real world scenario)

a simple way to make sure the entire result set of a query is being read, and not paged in the client,is to create a new table

e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS 
SELECT * FROM employee
```

and finally you may need to analyze your indexes after you fill your tables...
e.g:

```
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(     
    METHOD_OPT => 'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO'
   ,OWNNAME => 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
   ,TABNAME => 'EMPLOYEE'      
   ,ESTIMATE_PERCENT => NULL     
   ,CASCADE => TRUE);
```

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm